# Order by File Creation/Modified Date Not Working PHP

Tags: php

Right, this is really frustrating me.

I have 3 directions (dir1/dir2/dir3) when an index.php file in the root which I have posted below.

Each folder has a list of images in, they are automatically named and place into each of the folders. These are displayed in a table in 3 columns, with another 2 columns before these to show the number of rows and the date and time of each file. The first column of the 3 directories is suppose to order by DESC to show the latest file first. However, it shows the date and time in the wrong order, for example at the top it says February 28th (time) then another 28th of February (time) one, then two 26th of February (time), then some more of 28th!? Where it should be sorting latest dates first then oldest below. Can any one assist?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dirname = "dir1";
$dirnameTwo = "dir2";
$dirnameThree = "dir3";

$cam1 = scandir($dirname, SORT_DESC);
$cam2 = scandir($dirnameTwo, SORT_DESC);
$cam3 = scandir($dirnameThree, SORT_DESC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='max-age=0' />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT' />
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />
</head>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .pi-title {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pi-title">
            <h3>Test</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container col-md-12">
            <table class="table" border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#ccc'>
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">File Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">1 </th>
                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
                    $directories = implode(',', [ $dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree]);
                    $items = glob("./{{$directories}}/*", GLOB_BRACE);
                    $dirs = array($dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree);
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                        if (file_exists($items[$i])) {
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='3'>$i</font></td>";
                            echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='3' color='red'>" . date("F d Y H:i", filemtime($items[$i]));
                            echo "</font></td>";
                        }
                        print("

           <td><img src='$dirs[0]/$cam1[$i]' height='80' width='80'></td>
           <td><img src='$dirs[1]/$cam2[$i]' height='80' width='80'></td>
           <td><img src='$dirs[2]/$cam3[$i]' height='80' width='80'></td>

   ");
                        if ($i === 12) break;
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the existing issue in the table?

Comment: @dmikester1 I've added image to post

Comment: After you run `glob`, I don't see where you are sorting the `$items` array.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, looks like `glob` automatically does sort alphabetically.  Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

`scandir` orders ascending or descending alphabetically. But you want to sort by the date it has been last modified. So you need to apply a sorting function on it. For example you can do it with [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) and [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

```
$items = glob ...
uasort($items, function($a,$b) { return filemtime($a) > filemtime($b); })
```

Flip `filemtime($a) > filemtime($b)` to `filemtime($a) < filemtime($b)` for asc/desc
http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#refsect1-function.scandir-parameters

Comment: Any errors or simply not working? :D Try dumping a bit, give me input :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've been using for this (a snippet I've had around for a while):

```
public function scanLatestFile($directory) {
    // ignore any files that you don't want scanned
    $ignoredFiles = array('.index.php', '.htaccess');

    // Create new array to store the list of files
    $filesToSearch = array();

    // Scan the directory passed in
    foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, $ignoredFiles)) continue;

        // Add the filemtime so you can sort it
        $filesToSearch[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
    }

    // Sort by latest file
    arsort($filesToSearch);
    $filesToSearch = array_keys($filesToSearch);

    // Return latest file if it exists
    return ($filesToSearch) ? $filesToSearch : false;
}
```

This will return the latest file in the directory, also the ignore files are good to exclude anything you don't want.